# How to make a formula shorter

Tags: excel, formula

I have three pieces of information: quantity, weight per piece and a limit. What I need is for the weight per piece to multiple without passing the limit and the quantity.

I made a code, but the thing is the data of quantity varies and the code used is very long.

```
=ROUND(IFS((F13*G13)<H13,F13*G13,((F13-1)*G13)<H13,((F13-1)*G13),
 ((F13-2)*G13)<H13,,((F13-3)*G13)<H13,,((F13-4)*G13)<H13,,((F13-5)*G13)<H13,,
 ((F13-6)*G13)<H13,(F13-6)*G13,((F13-7)*G13)<H13,(F13-7)*G13,
 ((F13-8)*G13)<H13,(F13-8)*G13,((F13-9)*G13)<H13,(F13-9)*G13,
 ((F13-10)*G13)<H13,(F13-10)*G13,((F13-11)*G13)<H13, (F13-11)*G13,
 ((F13-12)*G13)<H13,(F13-12)*G13,((F13-13)*G13)<H13,(F13-13)*G13,
 ((F13-14)*G13)<H13,(F13-14)*G13,((F13-15)*G13)<H13,(F13-15)*G13,
 ((F13-16)*G13)<H13, (F13-16)*G13,((F13-17)*G13)<H13,(F13-17)*G13,
 ((F13-18)*G13)<H13,(F13-18)*G13),-2)+200
```

Here is the input and expected result, if no condition matches returns `#N/A`.

[image: 1]

Comment: Build a table, and then use vlookup approximate match. https://www.myexcelonline.com/blog/vlookup-approximate-match-in-excel/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the +200 at the end of the formula is supposed to be included in the limit or not so just adjust the formula accordingly

```
=ROUND(IF(G13*F13+200>=H13,H13,F13*G13+200),-2)
```

Multiply the quantity and the weight and add 200.

If the result is equal to or greater than the limit, set the result to the limit.

Otherwise use the results of the quantity * weight + 200

And then round it according to your initial formula

Answer (score 0):

This is what your `IFS()` looks like:

```
IFS(((F13-0)*G13)<H13,(F13-0)*G13,
    ((F13-1)*G13)<H13,(F13-1)*G13,
    ((F13-2)*G13)<H13,,
    ((F13-3)*G13)<H13,,
    ((F13-4)*G13)<H13,,
    ((F13-5)*G13)<H13,,
    ((F13-6)*G13)<H13,(F13-6)*G13,
    ((F13-7)*G13)<H13,(F13-7)*G13,
    ((F13-8)*G13)<H13,(F13-8)*G13,
    ((F13-9)*G13)<H13,(F13-9)*G13,
    ((F13-10)*G13)<H13,(F13-10)*G13,
    ((F13-11)*G13)<H13,(F13-11)*G13,
    ((F13-12)*G13)<H13,(F13-12)*G13,
    ((F13-13)*G13)<H13,(F13-13)*G13,
    ((F13-14)*G13)<H13,(F13-14)*G13,
    ((F13-15)*G13)<H13,(F13-15)*G13,
    ((F13-16)*G13)<H13,(F13-16)*G13,
    ((F13-17)*G13)<H13,(F13-17)*G13,
    ((F13-18)*G13)<H13,(F13-18)*G13)
```

I see three issues:

- the cases for 2 up to 5 are missing. Are you sure this is correct?
- it looks like (for a general 'x'):
  `IF ((F13-x)*G13)<H13 THEN (F13-x)*G13`, you can calculate the resulting value quite easily, isn't it?
- why do you stop at 18?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it as follows:

```
=LET(A, A2, B, B2, C, C2, seq, SEQUENCE(19,,0),
 out, IF((seq > 1) * (seq < 6), 0, (A - seq)*B),
 ROUND(@FILTER(out, (A - seq)*B < C, NA()), -2) + 200)
```

and extend it down, or use the array version as follow in cell `D2`:

```
=LET(A, A2:A3, B, B2:B3, C, C2:C3, seq, SEQUENCE(19,,0),
  MAP(A,B,C, LAMBDA(x,y,z, LET(out, IF((seq > 1) * (seq < 6), 0, (x - seq)*y),
  ROUND(@FILTER(out, (x - seq)*y < z, NA()), -2) + 200))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

The [implicit intersection operator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34) (`@`) ensures to get the first element of `FILTER` result, which is equivalent to get the first condition that matches. If no condition matches, then it returns `NA()`. The name `out`, has the result in the same order it should be tested via `IFS`. Using `SEQUENCE` allows to simplify the process.